# Pinvoke for struct

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke

I have the following struct definition:

```
#ifndef struct_emxArray_real_T
#define struct_emxArray_real_T
struct emxArray_real_T
{
    real_T *data;
    int32_T *size;
    int32_T allocatedSize;
    int32_T numDimensions;
    boolean_T canFreeData;
};
#endif /*struct_emxArray_real_T*/
```

and would like to use it in C# via PInvoke. The struct is meant to represent a matrix. Any C# struct code would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Someone has made an attempt [here](http://dotnetforum.net/topic/37251-c-how-to-call-a-c-function/):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1)]
public unsafe struct mytype
{
public double* data;
public int* size;
public int allocatedSize;
public int numDimensions;
public bool canFreeData;
}
```

but did not get it to work.

Comment: Your question was how to translate the struct definition. How to populate its members is a completely different matter.

Comment: Fair enough. Will post another question.

Comment: @David, I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925478/initialisation-of-struct-for-pinvoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# structs do not support pointer types.

Instead, pointers must be ported as `IntPtr`; you can use the `Marshal` class to resolve the pointer.

Therefore, you should write something like

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct mytype
{
    public IntPtr data;
    public IntPtr size;
    public int allocatedSize;
    public int numDimensions;
    public bool canFreeData;
}
```

Check what size your `boolean_T` type is; you may need to use the `[MarshalAs(...)]` attribute to specify the correct size.