# Matlab C++ - Receive Dynamic Size Output type (emxArray_real_T)

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

I have converted some matlab code to C++ using coder.

`void myfunction(const emxArray_real_T *input, emxArray_real_T *output){ ... }`

I have setup to send `emxArray_real_T` type inputs without any issues. How do I setup to receive dynamic sized output in C++ which is calling `myfunction`?

Code updated:

```
main(){ 
. 
. 
. 
double *inputVec; 
inputVec=(double*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(double)); 
emxArray_real_T *input;
emxArray_real_T *output;

input=emxCreateWrapper_real_T(&inputVec[0],1,1000); 
output = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(NULL,0,0);

myfunction(input,output); 

emxDestroyArray_real_T(input);
emxDestroyArray_real_T(output);
.
.
}
```

This compiles just fine but errors out saying
`*** glibc detected *** /data/myscript : double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000de54920 ***`

Answer (score 1):

You may check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271438/3297440 which seems to cover a similar issue.

In this particular case, the issue is likely that the memory pointed to by `output` was never initialized.  You can use one of the `emxCreate*` functions in `myfunction_emxAPI.h` to initialize an empty `emxArray` and pass that in.  The choice between `emxCreateWrapper_real_T` and `emxCreate_real_T` relies on whether or not you want to own the memory allocated for the data.  The former puts the ownership in your hands and the latter is used when the `emxArray` owns the memory.

Something like:

```
output = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(NULL,0,0);
```

before the call to `myfunction` should do the trick.

By the way, don't forget to call:

```
emxDestroyArray_real_T(input);
emxDestroyArray_real_T(output);
```

at the end to clean up any memory allocated inside of the `emxArrays`.  Even if the wrapper functions are used, storage for the size vectors may be allocated.

Comment: I have updated the code as you had mentioned. I am still having the same issue `double free or corruption`. Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: Curious, I just tested some code that looks about the same as yours where `myfunction` just multiplies the input by 2.  Does the crash pinpoint the location of the double free?  Could you try to build the code debug and run it in a debugger to pinpoint the location?  There must be something freeing memory in an invalid manner that needs to pinpointed.

Comment: One other thing to check.  Are there functions `myfunction_initialize/terminate` in `myfunction.h`?  If so, they should be called once before/after, respectively, the call to `myfunction`.  Those will be present to initialize any persistent data necessary.