# Matlab Coder and Arduino IDE emxCreateWrapper_real_T

Tags: c++, arduino, matlab-coder

I builded a neural net in Matlab and created a function, which uses the NN. I genereated C++ code from that function to use it on my Arduino Yun.

In the Arduino IDE I first wrote #include "NeuralNetwork.h" and had no problem to compile but I am not sure how to call the generated function from the matlab coder. The function header is

```
void NeuralNetwork(const emxArray_real_T *Data, double activity_data[], int
               activity_size[2], double *percent)
```

what type of data is emxArray_real_T? in Matlab Data is a inf x 5 Matrix.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662937/matlab-c-receive-dynamic-size-output-type-emxarray-real-t) I found some one using the emxCreateWrapper_real_T function, but if I use this function in Arduino IDE I only get the error:

```
'emxCreateWrapper_real_T' was not declared in this scope

   input = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(input_d,5,6);
```

I can't find such a function in any file created from matlab coder, where can I find that?

I am using Matlab R2016a.

My loop function in Arduino is:

```
void loop() {

  //input data are samples from a 3D Accelerometer
  double input [6][5] = { {30.38,0.584,0.106,0.253,1},  //walking
                          {30.4,0.772,0.059,0.461,1},   //walkinh
                          {1.98,0.026,0.13,1.031,2},    //sitting
                          {2.0,0.01,0.102,1.03,2},      //sitting
                          {5.0,-1.135,0.035,0.099,3},   //standing
                          {5.02,-1.14,0.039,0.09,3}};   //standing

 //emxArray_real_T *input;

  double activity[6];     //output from NN
  double percent = 0;     //amound of recognized data
  int act_size[2];        //???

  print_inp(input);     //just prints the input array to the serial interface

 // input = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(input,5,6);
  NeuralNetwork(input,activity,act_size,&percent);



  delay(50000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you're using but...

The error you get is "was not declared in this scope", so the compiler don't know the symbol `emxCreateWrapper_real_T` in the point you use it.

You should include the header of the file where `emxCreateWrapper_real_T()` is defined; or call it with the right namespace... I don't know exactly.

I've found [an example](http://www.gomatlab.de/matlab-coder-implementierung-in-cundund-t34416.html) of use where the included files are

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "arcl3d.h"
#include "arcl3d_initialize.h"
#include "arcl3d_terminate.h"
#include "arcl3d_emxAPI.h"
#include "arcl3d_emxutil.h"
```

so I suppose that `emxCreateWrapper_real_T()` is defined in "arcl3d_emxAPI.h" or in "arcl3d_emxutil.h".

My suggestion is: try including both of they.

If this doesn't work, try showing us the full code; including included files.

p.s: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I found a file named "_coder_NeuralNetwork_api.c" and a header file. In the header file the struct emxArray_real_T is declared but in the .c file is no emxCreateWrapper_real_T function but I found:

```
static void emxInit_real_T(const emlrtStack *sp, emxArray_real_T **pEmxArray,
  int32_T numDimensions, boolean_T doPush)
{
  emxArray_real_T *emxArray;
  int32_T i;
  *pEmxArray = (emxArray_real_T *)emlrtMallocMex(sizeof(emxArray_real_T));
  if (doPush) {
    emlrtPushHeapReferenceStackR2012b(sp, (void *)pEmxArray, (void (*)(void *))
      emxFree_real_T);
  }

  emxArray = *pEmxArray;
  emxArray->data = (real_T *)NULL;
  emxArray->numDimensions = numDimensions;
  emxArray->size = (int32_T *)emlrtMallocMex((uint32_T)(sizeof(int32_T)
    * numDimensions));
  emxArray->allocatedSize = 0;
  emxArray->canFreeData = true;
  for (i = 0; i < numDimensions; i++) {
    emxArray->size[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

can I also use that function,if yes, what are the input arguements??

But there is the next problem.... whithin that included header file another .h named "_coder_NeuralNetwork_mex.h" is included and that one needs a "mex.h" but the matlab coder didn't create such a file.

The content of _coder_NeuralNetwork_mex.h is:

```
#ifndef _CODER_NEURALNETWORK_MEX_H
#define _CODER_NEURALNETWORK_MEX_H

/* Include Files */
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tmwtypes.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "emlrt.h"
#include "_coder_NeuralNetwork_api.h"

/* Function Declarations */
extern void mexFunction(int32_T nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int32_T nrhs, const
  mxArray *prhs[]);
extern emlrtCTX mexFunctionCreateRootTLS(void);

#endif
```

I don't know if I have to use this files, beacuse they are created in the separte folder from the matlab coder.

Answer (score 0):

I found something the coder generated what might help:

```
//
// Academic License - for use in teaching, academic research, and meeting
// course requirements at degree granting institutions only.  Not for
// government, commercial, or other organizational use.
// File: main.cpp
//
// MATLAB Coder version            : 3.1
// C/C++ source code generated on  : 07-Jun-2016 19:17:39
//

//***********************************************************************
// This automatically generated example C main file shows how to call
// entry-point functions that MATLAB Coder generated. You must customize
// this file for your application. Do not modify this file directly.
// Instead, make a copy of this file, modify it, and integrate it into
// your development environment.
//
// This file initializes entry-point function arguments to a default
// size and value before calling the entry-point functions. It does
// not store or use any values returned from the entry-point functions.
// If necessary, it does pre-allocate memory for returned values.
// You can use this file as a starting point for a main function that
// you can deploy in your application.
//
// After you copy the file, and before you deploy it, you must make the
// following changes:
// * For variable-size function arguments, change the example sizes to
// the sizes that your application requires.
// * Change the example values of function arguments to the values that
// your application requires.
// * If the entry-point functions return values, store these values or
// otherwise use them as required by your application.
//
//***********************************************************************
// Include Files
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "NeuralNetwork.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "NeuralNetwork_terminate.h"
#include "NeuralNetwork_emxAPI.h"
#include "NeuralNetwork_initialize.h"

// Function Declarations
static emxArray_real_T *argInit_d7351x5_real_T();
static double argInit_real_T();
static void main_NeuralNetwork();

// Function Definitions

//
// Arguments    : void
// Return Type  : emxArray_real_T *
//
static emxArray_real_T *argInit_d7351x5_real_T()
{
  emxArray_real_T *result;
  static int iv0[2] = { 2, 5 };

  int idx0;
  int idx1;

  // Set the size of the array.
  // Change this size to the value that the application requires.
  result = emxCreateND_real_T(2, *(int (*)[2])&iv0[0]);

  // Loop over the array to initialize each element.
  for (idx0 = 0; idx0 < result->size[0UL]; idx0++) {
    for (idx1 = 0; idx1 < 5; idx1++) {
      // Set the value of the array element.
      // Change this value to the value that the application requires.
      result->data[idx0 + result->size[0] * idx1] = argInit_real_T();
    }
  }

  return result;
}

//
// Arguments    : void
// Return Type  : double
//
static double argInit_real_T()
{
  return 0.0;
}

//
// Arguments    : void
// Return Type  : void
//
static void main_NeuralNetwork()
{
  emxArray_real_T *Data;
  double activity_data[7351];
  int activity_size[2];
  double percent;

  // Initialize function 'NeuralNetwork' input arguments.
  // Initialize function input argument 'Data'.
  Data = argInit_d7351x5_real_T();

  // Call the entry-point 'NeuralNetwork'.
  NeuralNetwork(Data, activity_data, activity_size, &percent);
  emxDestroyArray_real_T(Data);
}

//
// Arguments    : int argc
//                const char * const argv[]
// Return Type  : int
//
int main(int, const char * const [])
{
  // Initialize the application.
  // You do not need to do this more than one time.
  NeuralNetwork_initialize();

  // Invoke the entry-point functions.
  // You can call entry-point functions multiple times.
  main_NeuralNetwork();

  // Terminate the application.
  // You do not need to do this more than one time.
  NeuralNetwork_terminate();
  return 0;
}

//
// File trailer for main.cpp
//
// [EOF]
//
```

But I am not sure how to use the function "static emxArray_real_T *argInit_d7351x5_real_T()" it says change the size to the value that the application requires but what do I have to change? For example I want to use a 10x5 Array, do I have to change the first value in iv0[] to 10??? 
To get the input values (in my first post the variable input[][]) can I replace the function call of "argInit_real_T()" to input[idx0][idx1] if I create that variable within that function or as global?