# Convert vector<> to emxArray_real_T in C++ after code-generation from MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

I have converted some matlab code to C++ using the MATLAB coder.

I am aware that there are some questions similar to this one, but none of the explanations I found did help with my problem, which is somewhat different.

The generated code for C++ gives me the following function:

```
void getTargetPoint(const emxArray_real_T *eyeMatrix, const emxArray_real_T
                *HypAlpha, const emxArray_real_T *HypCov, const
                emxArray_real_T *HypMean, const double xs[4], double Ymu[3])
```

Where Ymu is the output I am looking for. However, even if I defined my inputs as arrays of undetermined size in the converter, they are vectors of vectors in my code:

```
eyeMatrix = vector<vector <double>>
```

They all have different dimensions, for instance, eyeMatrix = [968x4], but in any other case it could be [anything x 4]

I have tried many things, but I cannot manage to convert my input data (vector of vectors) into type: emxArray_real_T

Is there anyway to do this? Or should I convert my input data into something else and then into emxArray_real_T?

Any help or idea is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is each vector different size in vector<vector <> >?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that `eyeMatrix` is a rectangular matrix (i.e. each inner vector has the same length) since the generated code likely is meant to work with non-ragged arrays.

You can check out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271438/3297440

and the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/c-code-interface-for-unbounded-arrays-and-structure-fields.html?refresh=true#bsp2zlh) for an overview of working with `emxArray*` data types.

To summarize the answer, you'll have functions declared in the file `<name>_emxAPI.h` that look like:

```
extern emxArray_real_T *emxCreateWrapper_real_T(double *data, int rows,
                                                int cols);
extern emxArray_real_T *emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols);
```

You'll notice that the first takes a `double *`. This should be a pointer to your data stored in column-major order.

Since `eyeMatrix` is likely in row-major order and may not actually be contiguous (I'm not aware of a guarantee that nested `std::vectors`  result in contiguous data) a first step can be to call `emxCreate_real_T` with the proper dimensions.

This allocates and returns an `emxArray_real_T` which we can call `emx`. `emx->size` will have 2 elements which are the dimensions you set. The field `emx->data` will be a pointer to `rows*cols` values (`double` values in your case). Then you can just copy the data from `eyeMatrix` to `emx->data` in a column-major fashion. So if your matrix is:

```
1, 2
3, 4
```

The data in `emx->data` should be:

```
1, 3, 2, 4
```

From there, just pass `emx` as the input.

Lastly, don't forget to call the proper `emxDestroyArray*` functions to clean up any allocated memory when you are done with the `emxArray_real_T` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RyanLivingston, I will try to work it out, I think I understood now how emxArray wants to receive the data!

Comment: Sounds great, you're quite welcome @Slash. Post back if you have other questions.

Comment: My code works great @RyanLivingston! Thanks again, I really appreciate it