# error: ''cannot convert 'uint8* {aka unsigned int*}' to 'const emxArray_uint8_T*'?'?

Tags: c++, image, matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I have written a matlab function to calculate entropy of image "`ent=entropoy(image)`" and convert it to c++ function by `matlab` coder.

I do some calculation at ent in `c++` file then try to convert all c++ code to matlab function.

I received the

> error: 'cannot convert 'uint8* {aka unsigned int*}' to 'const
>   emxArray_uint8_T*'

in entropy function

How declare image 'which input from matlab' in mex function  and use it correctly in entropy function?

Comment: How is `emxArray_uint8_T` defined? Quite likely that `uint8**` is required.

Comment: And why does the compiler believe that `uint8` is `unsigned int`?

Comment: I did suspect sarcasm, however its completely *[...] obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary*, so I assumed best intentions

Comment: @Ander As a matter of fact, it is not. I genuinely suspect that funky compiler to have defined `uint8` as a 64bits integer. I've just said it in a mocking manner (seriously, who would _dare_!?).

Answer (score 1):

To create an `emxArray_uint8_T` you'll need to use some of the helper functions that Coder generates for you like `emxCreate_uint8_T`.

The generated `emxArray_*_T` types from MATLAB Coder are structs used to store dynamically allocated data in the generated code. They contain a data pointer, size vector, and other metadata to manage dynamic allocation.

In MATLAB R2015a and newer, look for the files `main.c` and `main.h` in the generated code under the `examples` directory. Those will give you an example C or C++ main function that show you how to properly construct inputs and invoke the generated code.

The answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271438/3297440

also covers using the generated `emxArray` types in more detail and gives links to the MATLAB Coder documentation.