# Call C functions from Swift 4

Tags: c, swift, matlab

I've generated C code from MATLAB by using the codegen tool. The function can be described as follows:

```
function [result] = calculate_data(my_matrix)
    for idx = 1:length(my_matrix)
        result = result + sum(my_matrix(idx,1:3));
    end
end
```

When using the codegen tool, I explicitly stated that my_matrix is a type of double(:inf, 3). In other words, the number of rows is unbounded, but it will have 3 columns. When the code is generated, this is the function that is generated that I am to execute:

```
calculate_data(my_matrix : UnsafePointer<emxArray_real_T>!, result : UnsafeMutablePointer<emxArray_real_T>!)
```

emxArray_real_T is defined as follows in a different c file:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

When I see my initialization options for the above class, this one in particular makes sense:

```
emxArray_real_T.init(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>!, size: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!, allocatedSize: Int32, numDimensions: Int32, canFreeData: boolean_T)
```

I've tried to follow [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer) as a means to wrap my head around how to call the generated C code, but I think I might be missing a basic step. Here is what I am doing:

```
// create an 2d array with some fake data
var mySampleData = [[Double]]();
for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    mySampleData.append([1.1, 2.2, 3.3]);
}

// begin fulfilling requirements for emxArray_real_T
var data_pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: 3);
data_pointer.initialize(from: mySampleData)
```

However, the above code throws an error stating that:

```
Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred
```

I take it that I am then doing something completely wrong, and am probably on an incorrect path. There is a similar post that relates to my question, [How to convert float[][] type array to "emxArray_real_T *x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285640/how-to-convert-float-type-array-to-emxarray-real-t-x) , however the provided solution seems to be for C, as opposed to for Swift 4. How can I effectively call a C function using Swift 4, and meet the requirements of the emxArray_real_T.init method? Using fake data is ok to demonstrate the basic principle.

Comment: Just wanted to check about a few things before trying to help.  I haven't used MATLAB in years, but it looks like the function reduces `my_matrix` to a 1x1 matrix (`result`) of type `double`.  The generated code is, however, more general, allowing a transform from an MxN to KxL matrix.  Are these assumptions correct? Also, the generated `calculate_data` function must have been a C function, but it is not shown; instead, only its Swift representation is given.  What does the C function look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a simple Xcode project with mocked C constructs for the struct `emxArray_real_T` and the function `calculate_data` I can run the following code successfully. To create an object of type `emxArray_real_T` I do

```
var data: [Double] = (0 ..< 12).map(Double.init)
var size: [Int32] = [4, 3]

var array = emxArray_real_T(
    data: &data,
    size: &size,
    allocatedSize: 12,
    numDimensions: 2,
    canFreeData: false
)
```

This object can be passed to the function `calculate_data` like `calculate_data(&array, nil)`. In a real application `nil` would be another array object. For the sake of simplicity it is just used as a placeholder here.

Your second issue can be solved by using the right types (`[Double]` instead of `Double` in line 6):

```
var mySampleData = [[Double]]();
for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    mySampleData.append([i*1, i*2, i*3].map(Double.init));
}

let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<[Double]>.allocate(capacity: 3)
pointer.initialize(from: mySampleData, count: 3)

print((pointer + 0).pointee)
print((pointer + 1).pointee)
print((pointer + 2).pointee)

pointer.deallocate()
```

The output will be

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
```

as expected.

I have to admit that I used Swift 5.0.1. This should not make significant differences, though.

Comment: wrt to your first code block, where you initialize the data array. Are you saying that the goal is to create a 1d array, and when we specify the size, that's when it is treated as a matrix? so looking at the code, you say it is a 4 x 3. I take it that the 1:3,1 = 0:2, 1:3,2 = 3:5 . That would mean that we initialize it as a 1D array, but the size dictates the mapping. Does that sound correct?

Comment: nvm, it does work like that. i eneded up looking at the c code, and this sounds about right.

Comment: Exactly, this is how it works. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html) you find an explanation on how this structure is to be interpreted. Also you find some utility functions there to create objects in a little simpler way. By the way, using a 1d array to store data is a typical "pattern". Most of the numerical C libraries do it like that. One array access is cheaper than two (or even more for n-dimensional matrices).