# How to pass 2D array from Delphi to Matlab DLL

Tags: arrays, matlab, delphi

I have a problem.
I can pass 2D array from Delphi to C++ DLL that created by CodeBlocks.
My function in C++ DLL is :

```
double __declspec(dllexport)  __cdecl mainFunction(double** arr, int64 length)
```

And my Function In Delphi to call DLL is :

```
type
 DynMatrixDouble = array of array of double;
.
.
function arr(X:DynMatrixDouble; Y: integer):double; stdcall; external 'Array_dll.dll' name 'mainFunction';
```

This code works well and the values of the variables are transferred between the program and the dll.But when I convert a function that has a 2D array in input in Matlab to DLL or /to C++ to make DLL with CodeBlocks, It's no longer like the code above, this is :

```
double calc_det(int64m_T n, const emxArray_real_T *arr)
```

It seems I should make 2D Double array Variable In "emxArray_real_T" Type in Delphi and pass to DLL.
I searched and reached the link below:
[How to convert float[][] type array to "emxArray_real_T *x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285640/how-to-convert-float-type-array-to-emxarray-real-t-x)
But I couldn't find the answer to my question.My question is how can define "emxArray_real_T" type in Delphi for 2D Array and send it to dll ?
Can anyone help me how to do it right?
Thanks.

Comment: In your first method you have translated c++ `int64` to delphi's `integer` type, the latter being a 32-bit signed type and not the same as the 64-bit signed `int64`.  It will break if the value of `length` exceeds the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer.  For your question, the c++ header file should have a definition for `int64m_T` and `emxArray_real_T`.  A google search finds other matlab headers that define `typedef struct { uint32_T chunks[2]; } int64m_T;`, for example, so this is the structure you need to replicate in Delphi.

Comment: Thank you for response , But I want to know how to convert 2D Double array in Delphi to emxArray_real_T , because I should pass my array data to this DLL. I should make a record in delphi like emxArray_real_T structure , but how to convert my array into this record?

Comment: You need to find out what this structure is. Look at the Matlab docs.