# Calling methods using emxArray_real_T from C# causes Access Violation (0xc0000005)

Tags: c#, c, matlab

*[24012] the code as presented below works after creating the dll as c++, then as c again. Unclear for now why that is, may be completely unrelated reason (Matlab 2019a)*

*[240118_17:34 Edited for readability]*
Hope to find some support here with calling into matlab generated c-code from within c#. Unfortunately I cannot use matlabs new c#-code generation which is available in recent versions and spams the search-engine output. So I create c-code which I want to cal from C# (.net6.0). But I do experience access violations which I don't understand. Thanks for your thoughts in advance.

So, I have a matlab function

```
function data = selectBox(data, O, A, B, C)
   fprintf('selectBox: O = %.1f %.1f %.1f\n', O(1), O(2), O(3));
   [m,n] = size(data);
   fprintf('selectBox: data %.0f x %.0f\n', m, n);
   %% ...
end
```

Code generation produces a declaration that looks like that:

```
extern void selectBox(emxArray_real_T *data, const double O[3], const double A[3], const double B[3], const double C[3]);
```

This I use in c# like

```
[DllImport("selectBox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void selectBox(ref emxArray_real_T data, double[] O, double[] A, double[] B, double[] C);

public static void SelectPoints(double[,] data, double[] O, double[] A, double[] B, double[] C)
{
    // convert data to emxArray
    using EmxArrayRealTWrapper emxData = new(data);
    selectBox(ref emxData._value, O, A, B, C);
}
```

The EmxArrayRealTWrapper is implemented as proposed in [adapt wrapper class for two dimensional case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042298/adapt-wrapper-class-for-two-dimensional-case#15042498), which makes sense to me. I did modify the ._value-field to be public and not constant for testing.

Now, I experience access violation after seeing "selectBox: O = " printed on my terminal.

*True but not relevant as code is working now: I also tried to access the double-vectors through unsafe fixed pointers (`fixed (double* o = &O[0]){}`) using a signature like*

```
[DllImport("selectBox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private unsafe static extern void selectBox(ref emxArray_real_T data, double * O, double * A, double * B, double[] C);
```

*, alas, it did not help. Using fixed pointer for emxArray did not work neither.*

When I skip the step of printing the O-Vector I experience the violation when accessing the size (`[m,n] = size(data);`)

So, certainly I am doing something wrong with the memory management, anyone with a suggestion how to do it right?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Before using any function as for example fprintf read its description.

Comment: Do you have something in mind, Vlad? Of course I had checked and did not find any reason for it to fail. Also, the method passes SIL validation in matlab.

Comment: I wonder whether using the ref-keyword fixes the reference in memory as would be required(?) when calling into unmanaged code?